# Understanding virtualPaths using Request.MapPath()

Tags: c#, .net

I have reviewed a few of the questions on SO before posting here but I am a bit lost on physical path vs virtual path with my web application.

My web app triggers an exe to run called "JobRunner.exe", however, this file is in a different location on my drive. Lets say the file structure is as follows:

MainFolder/(Houses both webapp and exe folders below)

- Folder for WebApp/WebapplicationCode
- Folder for exe/bin/debug/JobRunner.exe

I want the code in the web app folder to call the job runner.  I am currently trying to do this with:

```
WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/JobRunner/bin/Debug/"),
FileName = Request.MapPath("JobRunner.exe")
```

This throws the file cannot be found, I have tried with absolute physical paths but this won't be scalable once the application is deployed.  How do I reference an exe that is one folder above and three folders down from my applications code base?  Am I just approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the WebApp folder is the 'application' in IIS, ie. MapPath("~/") will give you the path to WebApp.  If that assumption is correct then you need to do it like this.

```
FileName = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("~/"), @"..\jobrunner\bin\debug\jobrunner.exe");
```

because there is no way to directly map to a path above the web app (AFAIK - maybe there's something from the server context...)

Note that I'm unsure about the '\jobrunner\' part of this "..\jobrunner\bin\debug\jobrunner.exe", because your description of the folder setup is a little confusing, but hopefully you understand what I mean and how Path.Combine will allow you to go up one folder.